# Webpack font not found

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fonts, webpack

I started learning webpack and I have this small project

I'll be simplifying the content for brevity, hopefully it wont affect your understanding of the problem.

```
.
└── project
    ├── dist
    │   ├── fonts
    │   └── js
    ├── src
    │   ├── app
    │   │   ├── app.js
    │   │   └── component
    │   │       ├── component.css
    │   │       ├── component.directive.js
    │   │       └── component.html
    │   └── fontello
    ├── index.html
    ├── package.json
    └── webpack.config.js
```

I'm trying to keep everything inside my component encapsulated so I have:

component.directive.js

```
require('../../fontello/css/fontello.css');
require('./component.css');

var angular = require('angular');

...

module.exports = angular.module('directives.component', [])
    .directive('component', component)
    .name;
```

app.js

```
var angular = require('angular');   
var component = require('./component/component.directive.js');

...

angular.module('app', [component])
```

and webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + '/src',
    entry: {
        app: './app/app.js',
        vendor: ['angular']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'js/app.bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin("vendor", "js/vendor.bundle.js")
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
            exclude: ['./src/fontello']
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader?name=fonts/[name].[ext]'
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw'
        }]
    }
};
```

and I get for woff2/woff/ttf

> 404 Not Found. GET http://localhost:8080/fonts/fontello.woff2

what am I doing wrong?